# PHP strpos() return empty value

Tags: php, string, compare, strpos

I meet a strange thing with the PHP function strpos().
I have a function that check if a passed string is found in a txt file.
I can display the content of the file line by line but the strpos() doesn't return a value (nothing in fact). var_dump() of the return empty.

Can someone see a mistake, because I am lost.
Thank you in advance.

My function :

```
function checkIfExist($string)
{
    $path = "\\\\server\\temp\\test.txt";
    $file = file($path);
    foreach( $file as $line )
    {   
       echo $line; //display the string in this line
       $found = strpos($file,$string);
       echo $found; //display nothing, not even a boolean/int 
}
return $found;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're looking for the string in the entire contents of the file rather than in each line. Depending on the contents of `$string` and the file you may not be getting a match.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `$found = strpos($file,$string);` to `$found = strpos($line,$string);`

Answer (score 1):

Echoing a false boolean won't show up. Try changing it to a `var_dump` and you will see that it's a `boolean` set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have made a mistake when writen the code, this is the good one :

```
function checkIfExist($string)
{
    $path = "\\\\server\\temp\\test.txt";
    $file = file($path);
    foreach( $file as $line )
    {   
       echo $line; //display the string in this line
       $found = strpos($line,$string);
       echo $found; //display nothing, not even a boolean/int
       var_dump($found); //display boolena(false) for all the test even if the 
                         string is well present once.


}
    return $found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code give the same result

```
foreach( $file as $line )
{   
    echo $line; //display "www.google.be"
    echo $string; //also display "www.google.be"
    //but when I then if the line contain the string, the function doesn't find 
      it!!!
    $pos = stripos($line,$hostname);
    var_dump($pos); // FALSE for all the test
}
```

I have done this thes in other code, and I never had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Setup debugging, so you see the values of strpos. If debugging cannot be arranged than vardump $line and $string. You will probably get unexpected values. Also try avoiding typecasting-issues. Perhaps this will work better.

```
if (strpos($line,$string) != false){...}else{...}
```